# Angular2 renders template before parsing value

Tags: angular

I have an Ionic2 template, where img src is coming from a json. Rendering code is

```
<img src="questionSetChosen[currentQuestion]?.questiondata.questionImgUrl" alt="" *ngIf="questionSetChosen[currentQuestion]?.questiondata.questionImgUrl != 'NA' "/>
```

JSON is

```
"questiondata": {
                    "questionImgUrl": "NA",
                    "userChoice": "Z",
                    "isAnswered": "no",
                    "isCorrect": "NA",
                    "questionid": "tq0ql9ar50qg",
                    "explanation": "<p>Capsule Endoscopy is not suiëtable for patients with strictures.</p>",
                    "question": "Capsule Endoscopy-False statement is",
                    "reference": "Bailey and Love 26th Edition P/205"
                },
```

Despite using Elvis operator and *ngIf angular2 flashes blank img for a fraction of seconds on page load.

How can I prevent that.

Comment: looks okay. try `[src]` instead of `src` n let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *ngIf="questionSetChosen[currentQuestion]?.questiondata.questionImgUrl != 'NA' "
```

If that is coerced to null, it will evaluate to true (`null` != `'NA'` is true).

You'll want to short circuit that and null check first to prevent the image flicker.

Comment: 'NA' is the literal string. If json key questionImgUrl == 'NA' it should not display img tag. Thats my requirement.

Comment: Right, but you also want that to fail if it's null.  So you'll need to check if it's null as well to make sure it only displays if it's `not null` AND `not eq 'NA`.